Result returns in Python for adfuller tests
I use the following code to run a adfuller test on a time series "X":
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
X = df["Close"].values
adfuller(X, maxlag=None, regression="c", autolag='AIC', regresults=True)

The results returned by Python are:
(2.8197855029954364,
 1.0,
 {'1%': -3.430949746911846,
  '5%': -2.8618050548838534,
  '10%': -2.5669110835837743},
 <statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.ResultsStore at 0x1b605e5e050>)

What does <statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.ResultsStore at 0x1b605e5e050> mean? I expected the "full regression results".

Could  you check what version of statsmodels you have installed?  The documentation isn't as clear as it could be, but based on the current source code, because you passed regresults=True, it also acts as if you had passed store=True, which means it is returning the tuple of adfstat, pvalue, critvalues, resstore, where resstore is an object containing the results as attributes. <statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.ResultsStore at 0x1b605e5e050>is therepr` for the ResultsStore object.

Using                                                                                                                                           ```import statsmodels
statsmodels.version ´´´                                                                                                I receive the response '0.14.0'. Is that version of statsmodels ok?

Yes that should be fine. I believe the most recent version is 0.14.2. See the comment I put under Vikas's answer. You need to get just the fourth item in the returned tuple, and then get .resols.summary() from that.

To get the full regression table:
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
X = df["Close"].values
reg_res = adfuller(X, maxlag=None, regression="c", autolag='AIC', regresults=True)
print(reg_res[-1].resols.summary())

You can convert it to a simple DataFrame as well after adding:
import pandas as pd
regression_table = {
    'Variable': reg_res[-1].resols.model.exog_names,
    'Coefficient': reg_res[-1].resols.params,
    'Std. Error': reg_res[-1].resols.bse,
    't-Statistic': reg_res[-1].resols.tvalues,
    'P-Value': reg_res[-1].resols.pvalues
}
regression_df = pd.DataFrame(regression_table)
print(regression_df)


Thanks a lot for your help Vikas! However, using your code, I receive an error message as documented in the following:

This code won't work as adfuller() is returning a tuple.   Either get only the ResultsStore object by changing line 3 to _*, reg_res = adfuller(.....)  OR, the print line should be:
print(reg_res[4].resols.summary())  (or index -1 instead of 4)

Hi Rene. I have made the required edit and I think the code should work now. We needed to access the ResultsStore object first then print the summary as @nigh_anxiety has pointed out. The object is at the last position, hence used the '-1' index number.

Thanks a lot Vikas! I got my code working!

Is there any literature / site you can recommend for a beginner like me to deal with such problems? I bought the book "Introduction to Time Series Forecasting in Python" of Jason Brownlee. However the Python code use in this book is old and does not work with the current Python modules...

Thanks a lot for your help Vikas! If I run your first code:
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
X = df["Close"].values
reg_res = adfuller(X, maxlag=None, regression="c", autolag='AIC', regresults=True)
print(reg_res.resols.summary())

I receive the following error message:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 4
      2 X = df["Close"].values
      3 reg_res = adfuller(X, maxlag=None, regression="c", autolag='AIC', regresults=True)
----> 4 print(reg_res.resols.summary())

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'resols'

If I run your second code:
import pandas as pd
regression_table = {
    'Variable': reg_res.resols.model.exog_names,
    'Coefficient': reg_res.resols.params,
    'Std. Error': reg_res.resols.bse,
    't-Statistic': reg_res.resols.tvalues,
    'P-Value': reg_res.resols.pvalues
}
regression_df = pd.DataFrame(regression_table)
print(regression_df)

I receive a similar error message:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 3
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 regression_table = {
----> 3     'Variable': reg_res.resols.model.exog_names,
      4     'Coefficient': reg_res.resols.params,
      5     'Std. Error': reg_res.resols.bse,
      6     't-Statistic': reg_res.resols.tvalues,
      7     'P-Value': reg_res.resols.pvalues
      8 }
      9 regression_df = pd.DataFrame(regression_table)
     10 print(regression_df)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'resols'

Maybe there is something wrong with my Python-Version? I access Python 3 via JypyterLab 3.6.3
